# How do I turn off automatic switching of windows?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell-extension, viber

As I am typing in word, Viber message pops up and the Viber application opens and I go on typing my documents on the Viber message.

I want an automatic switch to turn the active window off in Ubuntu.

This is causing me troubles on a day to day basis. I have to minimize my Viber window to start working on Microsoft Office (Word) again.

```
android@android:~$ uname -a
Linux android 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
android@android:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
android@android:~$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.28.1
android@android:~$
```

Comment: Strange! In GNOME the default behaviour is exact opposite, the window opens in background a notification pops up saying "X is ready". Are you using another desktop environment instead of the 18.04 default GNOME?

Comment: yes its default gnome......

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-new-windows 'smart'` see if this helps, alternatively search for it in `dconf-editor -> org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> preferences`

Comment: @SkanderBejaoui sorry, doesnot work for me.

Comment: This seems specific to `viber` or are any other apps affected ?

Comment: Have you tried `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode 'mouse'`and keeping the mouse pointer in the document?

Comment: @nazar2sfive You could force viber window to stay below with wmctrl. The command to toggle on/off the below is `wmctrl -F -r "Window title" -b toggle,below`, window title is in the form "Viber your_phone_num", you can check that with `wmctrl -l` but first install wmctrl.

Answer (score 4):

seems following extension was activated. I don't remember installing it. I had to disable it .

[image]

Comment: Hmm... now how to ask a mod to get your bounty back? I've flagged your answer asking a mod to return your bounty. Hopefully that can be done :)

Comment: Bounties are non refundable except for extenuating circumstances (i.e. your question being closed as a duplicate). Sorry.